# How to use beans, defined in JSP useBean tags in servlets?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I use both JSP pages and servlets in my application. I have the following bean definitions in my JSPs:

```
jsp:useBean id="sesCtrl" class="com.ess.SesController" scope="session" 
jsp:useBean id="appCtrl" class="com.ess.AppController" scope="application"
```

As it can be seen, there is a "sesCtrl" object with session scope and "appCtrl" object with "application" scope. The question is: how can I access these objects in the servlets used in the same application?

Comment: You could try using  request.getSession().getAttribute("sesCtrl")  and request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("appCtrl")

Answer (score 0):

I found a detailed description here:
http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=53309